# Remove line from marker in legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How to remove line located in center of square in legend. To leave there only square marker?

[image: image to help describe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript use legend property

```
 "legend": {
        "useGraphSettings": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a SVG image, you can remove the circle element.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: I know that I can hide it in CSS. But I'm building reusable component in angular2 and want to configure AmChart in JS.